# How to give message for NotNull Annotations from javax.validation.constraints

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, constraints

I am using `NotNull` Annotation the following way,but does not display message

> @NotNull(message="Not Null,Put Some value")
>    private String UserName,
>   Password, Repassword,Address;

How to put message for `NotNull` Annotation

Comment: How are you doing to display the validation message?